# SSRS using calendar to select date parameters

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a basic report that has 7 fields.

I want the data to be parameter driven.

StartDate and EndDate are the fields I want the user to choose before the report is rendered.

If you see the first image, I have laid out the report and created a StartDate & EndDate parameters, and 2 text boxes with [@START_DATE] & [@END_DATE] as the values. I have set their field type to Number>Date. I expected that when I ran the report I would be given two small calander windows where I could select a start date and an end date. I have seen this done in other reports, so I know this is possible. But what I see when I run the report is in image2.

I have tried putting in the Where clause:

```
where (START_DATE IN (@START_DATE)) AND (END_DATE IN (@END_DATE))
```

But this just allows me to manually type the date I want in. I need a calendar display.

Any ideas?

[image]

[image]

Comment: good man @selectdistinct

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to set the datatype of the parameter as  Date/Time. Do a right click on the parameter of StartDate in your case and you will see the property as below

[image]

Comment: Realised this after I posted the question, thanks for the clear answer though, +1